# Excel function: Matching multiple rows and columns

Tags: excel, matrix, match

Is there a way to match a matrix of data with a single cell value (text value):

One  | Seven   | Three
Four | Elleven | Nine
Six  | Two     | Twelve

Match: Two

All it needs to do is matching two with the matrix. A simple Yes/No, 1 for match 0 for none or similar output is fine.

Br
Koefoed

Answer (score 0):

You want "INDEX MATCH"

it's a magical combination of functions that result in exactly what you want.

[INDEX MATCH Tutorial](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/)

Comment: Index match only works on a single row/column as far as i can see?

Ive been looking at this solution, but i cant get it to work: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/516742-how-return-results-position-2d-array.html

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone should be interested, i got it working with the following:

```
IF(SUMPRODUCT((Data!$J$3:$DH$27=$B2)*ROW(Data!$J$3:$DH$27))>0;TRUE;FALSE)
```

Comment: That's good but I'm willing to bet that there is a much simpler method

Comment: I that case, it would be nice to know.